# Vastly incorrect answers obtained by increasing WorkingPrecision with modified Bessel functions

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, bugs, numerics, special-functions

**Bug introduced in 7.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.0**

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115629/strange-phenomenon-occurring-in-analytic-integration-result-involving-bessel-fun) regarding numerical instabilities occurring with modified Bessel functions. In trying to explore J.M.'s answer to that question in greater depth by setting `WorkingPrecision -> 50` (as advised in the other answer by xslittlegrass), I obtained vastly different (and incorrect!) results than when not explicitly setting a non-default `WorkingPrecision` (see below for plots). I am trying to figure out why this is occurring and was advised to make a separate question regarding this.

The function that I am attempting to plot (for fixed $b$, as a function of $a$) is

```
f[a_, b_] := (a^2 Exp[a^2/(8 b)] (BesselK[3/4, a^2/(8 b)] - 
  BesselK[1/4, a^2/(8 b)]))/(8 Sqrt[a b^3])
```

which is the analytic solution to

```
Integrate[x^2 Exp[-a x^2 - b x^4], {x, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]
```

I also plot the numerical solution to this,

```
g[a_,b_] := NIntegrate[x^2 Exp[-a x^2 - b x^4], {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

Without any regards to `WorkingPrecision`, I obtain the following plot:

```
amin = 10^-10; amax = 0.1; bval = 10^-3;
LogLogPlot[{f[a, bval], g[a, bval]}, {a, amin, amax}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Even with explicitly giving the variable/bounds higher precision,

```
amin = 1`50 10^-10; amax = 0.1`50; bval = 1`50 10^-3;
```

the plot remains the same as above. If, however, I add in `WorkingPrecision -> 50`, a plot with function values many orders of magnitude higher is obtained:

```
amin = 1`50 10^-10; amax = 0.1`50; bval = 1`50 10^-3;
LogLogPlot[{f[a, bval], g[a, bval]}, {a, amin, amax}, WorkingPrecision -> 50,
             PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The fact that this is occurring is worrisome, as I would generally expect the results obtained with higher `WorkingPrecision` to be more trustworthy; in this case, however, they are completely wrong -- here's a representative plot:

```
bval = 10^-3;
Plot[x^2 Exp[-a x^2 - bval x^4] /. a -> 10^-5, {x, -15, 15}]
```

[image]

Why is this happening? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you mean `Integrate` instead of `NIntegrate` in your definition of `g`?

Comment: I believe he did mean `NIntegrate[]`, @bb; he was comparing the solution I derived in the other thread with the results of numerical integration.

Comment: @J.M.  I understand your point.  However, `Assumptions` is not a legal option for `NIntegrate`.

Comment: Yes, prolly an error of copying, @bb...

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you for pointing that out – as J.M. correctly predicted, that was an error of copying, since $a$ and $b$ have to have actual numerical values for `NIntegrate` to return a value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LogPlot axes labels destroyed when working in high precision](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15628/logplot-axes-labels-destroyed-when-working-in-high-precision)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There appears to be a bug, not in `Integrate` or in `BesselK`, but in the vertical-axis `Ticks` of `LogLogPlot`.  Consider the simple case,

```
LogLogPlot[Exp[x], {x, 10^-10, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

as it should be.  However,

```
LogLogPlot[Exp[x], {x, 10^-10, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 50, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

In fact, any value of `WorkingPrecision` except `MachinePrecision` triggers this error.  Even `WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision` produces the error.

Comment: Oh my. That would be quite unfortunate. I will have to see if this issue arises for various functions when I'm at my computer again tomorrow morning – this is something that would somehow need to be reported to the appropriate Wolfram team, right?

Comment: @PhysicsCodingEnthusiast  Absolutely.  Will you do so, or do you wish me to?  Your call.

Comment: I can do so – is there a good way to do this? Should I provide a link to this question? I'll wait to do it until I'm at my computer again (currently on my phone) – in the meantime, perhaps others will chime in with their own findings. Thanks!

Comment: @Physics, yes, please do link to this question as evidence if and when you make a report.

Comment: @PhysicsCodingEnthusiast  Report the bug [here](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback).  Do not be surprised, if the response is slow.

Comment: @PhysicsCodingEnthusiast The response is usually not slow.  But the developers do seem to take their time in fixing certain bugs.